# XMLHttpRequest sends empty form data every time I try to save form

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am having a problem where I try to save the form and every time it sends empty data to the server. 
This is only happening on Windows Chrome browser. On Mac Chrome, it is working perfectly fine.

```
try {
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary == 'undefined') {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function(text){
      var data = new ArrayBuffer(text.length);
      var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data, 0);
      for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) ui8a[i] = (text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
      this.send(ui8a);
    };
  }
} catch (e) {}


var AJAXSubmit = (function () {

  function ajaxSuccess () {
    /* console.log("AJAXSubmit - Success!"); */
    alert("Saved successfully");
    /* you can get the serialized data through the "submittedData" custom property: */
     //alert(JSON.stringify(this.submittedData)); 

  }

  function ajaxError() {

    alert("Sorry, there was an error. Please save again.");
  }

  function submitData (oData) {
    /* the AJAX request... */
    var oAjaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(oAjaxReq);
    oAjaxReq.submittedData = oData;
    oAjaxReq.timeout = 10000;
    oAjaxReq.ontimeout = ajaxError;
    oAjaxReq.onerror = ajaxError;

    if (oData.technique === 0) {
      /* method is GET */
      oAjaxReq.open("get", oData.receiver.replace(/(?:\?.*)?$/, oData.segments.length > 0 ? "?" + oData.segments.join("&") : ""), true);
      oAjaxReq.send(null);
    } else {
      /* method is POST */
      oAjaxReq.open("post", oData.receiver, true);
      if (oData.technique === 3) {
        /* enctype is multipart/form-data */
        var sBoundary = "---------------------------" + Date.now().toString(16);
        //oAjaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart\/form-data; boundary=" + sBoundary);
        oAjaxReq.sendAsBinary("--" + sBoundary + "\r\n" + oData.segments.join("--" + sBoundary + "\r\n") + "--" + sBoundary + "--\r\n");
        oAjaxReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(oAjaxReq.readyState==4 && oAjaxReq.status ==200 && oAjaxReq.response == "1"){
            oAjaxReq.onload = ajaxSuccess;
            }
            if(oAjaxReq.readyState==4 && oAjaxReq.status ==200 && oAjaxReq.response == "2"){
            oAjaxReq.onload = ajaxError;
            }
            if(oAjaxReq.readyState!=4 && oAjaxReq.status !=200){
            oAjaxReq.onload = ajaxError;
            }

        };
      } else {
        /* enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or text/plain */
        oAjaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", oData.contentType);
        oAjaxReq.send(oData.segments.join(oData.technique === 2 ? "\r\n" : "&"));

      }
    }
  }

  function processStatus (oData) {
    if (oData.status > 0) {  return; }
    /* the form is now totally serialized! do something before sending it to the server... */
    /* doSomething(oData); */
    /* console.log("AJAXSubmit - The form is now serialized. Submitting..."); */

    submitData (oData);
  }

  function pushSegment (oFREvt) {
    this.owner.segments[this.segmentIdx] += oFREvt.target.result + "\r\n";
    this.owner.status--;
    processStatus(this.owner);
  }

  function plainEscape (sText) {
    /* how should I treat a text/plain form encoding? what characters are not allowed? this is what I suppose...: */
    /* "4\3\7 - Einstein said E=mc2" ----> "4\\3\\7\ -\ Einstein\ said\ E\=mc2" */
    return sText.replace(/[\s\=\\]/g, "\\$&");
  }

  function SubmitRequest (oTarget) {
    var nFile, sFieldType, oField, oSegmReq, oFile, bIsPost = oTarget.method.toLowerCase() === "post";
    /* console.log("AJAXSubmit - Serializing form..."); */
    //console.log(oTarget);
    this.contentType = bIsPost && oTarget.enctype ? oTarget.enctype : "application\/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    this.technique = bIsPost ? this.contentType === "multipart\/form-data" ? 3 : this.contentType === "text\/plain" ? 2 : 1 : 0;
    this.receiver = oTarget.action;
    this.status = 0;
    this.segments = [];
    var fFilter = this.technique === 2 ? plainEscape : escape;
    for (var nItem = 0; nItem < oTarget.elements.length; nItem++) {
      oField = oTarget.elements[nItem];
      if (!oField.hasAttribute("name")) { continue; }
      sFieldType = oField.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT" ? oField.getAttribute("type").toUpperCase() : "TEXT";
      if (sFieldType === "FILE" && oField.files.length > 0) {
        if (this.technique === 3) {
          /* enctype is multipart/form-data */
          for (nFile = 0; nFile < oField.files.length; nFile++) {
            oFile = oField.files[nFile];
            oSegmReq = new FileReader();
            /* (custom properties:) */
            oSegmReq.segmentIdx = this.segments.length;
            oSegmReq.owner = this;
            /* (end of custom properties) */
            oSegmReq.onload = pushSegment;
            this.segments.push("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + oField.name + "\"; filename=\""+ oFile.name + "\"\r\nContent-Type: " + oFile.type + "\r\n\r\n");
            this.status++;
            oSegmReq.readAsBinaryString(oFile);
          }
        } else {
          /* enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or text/plain or method is GET: files will not be sent! */
          for (nFile = 0; nFile < oField.files.length; this.segments.push(fFilter(oField.name) + "=" + fFilter(oField.files[nFile++].name)));
        }
      } else if ((sFieldType !== "RADIO" && sFieldType !== "CHECKBOX") || oField.checked) {
        /* field type is not FILE or is FILE but is empty */
        this.segments.push(
          this.technique === 3 ? /* enctype is multipart/form-data */
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + oField.name + "\"\r\n\r\n" + oField.value + "\r\n"
          : /* enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded or text/plain or method is GET */
            fFilter(oField.name) + "=" + fFilter(oField.value)
        );
      }
    }

    processStatus(this);
  }

  return function (oFormElement) {
    if (!oFormElement.action) { return; }
    new SubmitRequest(oFormElement);
  };

})();
```

I used this code from the Mozilla Developers Page. Here's the link to it. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#A_little_vanilla_framework

Comment: Have you considered using jquery $.ajax. Here is a link that points to the official documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: $.ajax doesn't send files to the server. I have multiple files in this form.

Comment: In that case you should implement http handler and that handler can accept the byte array from the file from the httpcontext